# How to pass multiple arguments in pytest using command line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I want to pass inputs to my pytest file as a command line option. This question https://stackoverflow.com/a/42145604/8031479 was helpful but I don't know to add multiple parser adoptions.

I have tried adding this to my *conftest.py* file, but was not helpful:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    """
        This function is used to extract input1 and input2 values from the command line
    """
    parser.addoption(
        "--input1", action="store", default="input1"
    )
    parser.addoption(
        "--input2", action="store", default="input2"
    )
```

Contents of my test.py file:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture()
def get_input1(input1):
    print 'input1:', input1
    return input1

# @pytest.mark.unit
@pytest.fixture()
def get_input2(input2):
    print 'input2:', input2
    return input2

def test_hello(get_input1, get_input2):
    print 'testing pytest fixtures with command line options'
    print get_input1, get_input2
```

This is my command to run the *test.py* file:

```
py.test test.py --input1="hello" --input2="world"
```

I am getting this error message:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def get_input1(input1):
E       fixture 'input1' not found
>       available fixtures: cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, capsysbinary, doctest_namespace, get_input1, get_input2, metadata, monkeypatch, pytestconfig, record_property, record_xml_attribute, recwarn, tmp_path, tmp_path_factory, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory
>       use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.
```

Comment: Have you tried `--input1 value --input2 value`?

Comment: Yes @Adonis. I am getting the following error:

    `@pytest.fixture()
    def get_input1(input1):
    E       fixture 'input1' not found
    >       available fixtures: cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, capsysbinary, doctest_namespace, get_input1, get_input2, metadata, monkeypatch, pytestconfig, record_property, record_xml_attribute, recwarn, tmp_path, tmp_path_factory, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory
    >       use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.'

Comment: You need the generate tests function, too; reread the answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can make it work this way:

conftest.py:

```
import pytest


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--input1", action="store", default="default input1")
    parser.addoption("--input2", action="store", default="default input2")



@pytest.fixture
def input1(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--input1")


@pytest.fixture
def input2(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--input2")
```

test.py:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.unit
def test_print_name(input1, input2):
    print ("Displaying input1: %s" % input1)
    print("Displaying input2: %s" % input2)
```

CLI:

```
>py.test -s test.py --input1 tt --input2 12
================================================= test session starts =================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.7.0, pytest-4.1.1, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.1
rootdir: pytest, inifile:
collected 1 item

test.py Displaying input1: tt
Displaying input2: 12
.

============================================== 1 passed in 0.04 seconds ===============================================
```