# how to run pytest with args parsed into the test file?

Tags: python, command-line, parameter-passing, pytest, argparse

on MacOS, I want to run pytest in command line:

```
python3 -m pytest test_function_validation.py
```

However, **test_function_validation.py** has got **argparser** in it written as:

```
import pytest
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-f', action='store', nargs=1, dest='file_to_read')
args = parser.parse_args()
file_to_read = args.file_to_read[0] 
...etc
```

Question: I was running

> python3  -m pytest test_function_validation.py -f
>   input_data.json

And it complains:

```
pytest.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f input_data.json
```

I also tried:

> pytest test_function_validation.py -f
>   input_data.json

which result in error:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pytest: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.6: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

So, how can run a pytest with some arguments passed into the test file . I need to do this in command line in terminal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass arguments in pytest by command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40880259/how-to-pass-arguments-in-pytest-by-command-line)

Comment: `pytest` is running its own `argparse` (or equivalent), so you can only use commandline arguments that it accepts.  Your own script should be invoking the parser from a `if __name__` block so doesn't run when the script is imported.

Comment: A workaround:     
            import sys   //          
    sys.argv = ['myscript.py', '-f', 'my_file.txt']    //
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()    // ...

Comment: - but you say you need to pass the params via command line, so this is probably not a solution.