# how to pass parameters to pytest test?

Tags: python, pytest

Say I have this test in `tests.py`

```
def test_user(username='defaultuser'):
```

**Case 1**

I want to pass the username to test from the command line, something like

```
$ pytest tests.py::test_user user1  # could be --username=user1
```

How do I do that?

**Case 2**

I want to pass a list of usernames to test, like

```
$ pytest tests.py::test_user "user1, user2, user3"
```

I want to achieve something like

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("username", tokenize_and_validate(external_param))
def test_user(username):
    pass

def tokenize_and_validate(val):
    if not val:
        return 'defaultuser'
    return val.split(',')
```

How can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: Reference: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html

Answer (score 2):

When you pass a parameter from the command line at first you need to create a generator method to get the value from the command line this method run every test.

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    # This is called for every test. Only get/set command line arguments
    # if the argument is specified in the list of test "fixturenames".
    option_value = metafunc.config.option.name
    if 'name' in metafunc.fixturenames and option_value is not None:
        metafunc.parametrize("name", [option_value])
```

Then you can run from the command line with a command line argument:

```
pytest -s tests/my_test_module.py --name abc
```

[Follow the link for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42145604/6068032)

Comment: thanks! I guess I also need to add the "--name" option as in the solution you copied

Answer (score 0):

To mock the data, you can use [fixtures](https://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html) or use builtin `unittest` mocks.

```
from unittest import mock

@mock.patch(func_to_mock, side_effect=func_to_replace)
def test_sth(*args):
    pass
```

Command line [options](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html) are also available.