# Is there a way in PyTest to pass command line arguments to conftest.py directly?

Tags: python, pytest

I know that there is a way to pass args in tests itself [like it was shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42145604), but is there a way to pass in conftest.py directly? I want to configure some common stuff for all tests this way.
This is my conftest.py:

```
 import pytest
 from appium import webdriver
 import json
 import os

 from config import *

 CAPS_FILE = "android_9.0_emulator.json"


 def pytest_addoption(parser):
     parser.addoption("--desired-capabilities", action="store", default=CAPS_FILE)


 def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
     # This is called for every test. Only get/set command line arguments
     # if the argument is specified in the list of test "fixturenames".
     option_value = metafunc.config.option.name
     if 'desired-capabilities' in metafunc.fixturenames and option_value is not None:
         # metafunc.parametrize("desired_capabilities", [option_value])
         CAPS_FILE = option_value


 def get_desired_caps(json_file):
     with open(desired_caps_dir_path) as json_file:
         return json.load(json_file)


 @pytest.fixture(scope="session")
 def browser():
     driver = webdriver.Remote(appium_driver_url, desired_capabilities=get_desired_caps(CAPS_FILE))
     # driver = webdriver.Remote(appium_driver_url, desired_capabilities=get_desired_caps(metafunc.config.option))
     yield driver
     driver.quit()
```

**UPDATE**: or maybe I should use this function to initialize/configure conftest.py itself from command line:

```
def pytest_configure(config):
     option_val = config.option.name
     if 'desired-capabilities' in config.option and option_val is not None:
         CAPS_FILE = option_val
```

Or maybe there is a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
 def pytest_addoption(parser):
     desired_caps = None
     parser.addoption("--desired-capabilities", dest=desired_caps, action="store", default=CAPS_FILE)


 def pytest_configure(config):
     option_val = config.option.desired_capabilities
     if 'desired_capabilities' in config.option and option_val is not None:
         CAPS_FILE = option_val
```

**NOTE**: --desired-capabilities --> desired_capabilities (**dest** parameter seems broken or I'm missing something...)