# how to configure python test with custom arguments

Tags: python, pytest

i am trying to write test for external application

and i want to be able to configure them

is there any tool, that allows run 'PYTEST'?

`--my-custom-argument 42 --app-host some_host --etc`

and later in test use those **custom arguments**

or i can use another way to configure such things?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass arguments in pytest by command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40880259/how-to-pass-arguments-in-pytest-by-command-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are already using conftest.py you should be able to do something like:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "--cmdopt", action="store", default="type1", help="my option: type1 or type2"
    )
```

this is a good place to get started: [pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html)

Comment: thanks! since thene is no annotation above pytest_addoption i missundestod that