# Why is pytest giving me an "unrecognized option" error when I try and create a custom command line option?

Tags: python-3.x, command-line, pytest, conftest

I'm using Python 3.8 and pytest 6.0.1. How do I create a custom command line option for pytest? I thought it was as simple as adding this to conftest.py ...

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--option1', action='store_const', const=True)
```

but when I pytest, I get an unrecognized option error

```
# pytest --option1=Y -c tests/my_test.py 
ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --option1=Y
```

What's the right way to add a custom option?

**Edit:** I tried the answer given.  I included some other things in my tests/conftest.py file in case those are the reason the answer isn't working.  File contains

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    option1value = metafunc.config.getoption("--option1")
    print(f'Option1 Value = {option1value}')

def pytest_configure(config):
    use_docker = False
    try:
        use_docker = config.getoption("--docker-compose-remove-volumes")
    except:
        pass
    plugin_name = 'wait_for_docker' if use_docker else 'wait_for_server'
    if not config.pluginmanager.has_plugin(plugin_name):
        config.pluginmanager.import_plugin("tests.plugins.{}".format(plugin_name))
```

But output when running is

```
$ pytest -s --option1 tests/shared/model/test_crud_functions.py
ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --option1
  inifile: /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/my_project/pytest.ini
  rootdir: /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/my_project
```

Comment: If you use `store_const`, the option is handled as a flag and cannot have a value, e.g. you have to use `pytest --option1`. If you want to set different values, you can use the default `store` action instead.

Comment: I vote closing this as a dupe, there are lots of answers regarding custom cli args in `pytest` already, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/40880259/2650249 and linked questions there.

Comment: Might be a bit silly asking but: Are you sure you added this hook to your root conftest.py?

Comment: You mean "tests/conftest.py"?  Yes and I know it's in there because if I just run "pytest tests/shared/model/test_crud_functions.py" all by itself I get the error, "ValueError: no option named '--option1'".  Frustratingly, when I run "pytest --option1=abc tests/shared/model/test_crud_functions.py", I get the "pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --option1=abc" error.

Comment: Anyone trying this on Databricks might find it easier to set the env var `PYTEST_ADDOPTS` instead, as it tends not to work when using parameters in a job.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in a comment  `action='store_const'` makes your option a flag. The value you receive when you read option value provided it is specified on cli is the one specified by `const` i.e. `True` in your case.

**Try this:**
add below function to conftest.py

```py
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    option1value = metafunc.config.getoption("--option1")
    print(f'Option1 Value = {option1value}')
```

1. pytest invoked with option `pytest -s --option1`

   **Output will have :** Option1 Value = True
2. pytest invoked without option `pytest -s`

   **Output will have :** Option1 Value = None

`action=store` might give you the desired behavior.

**Solution**:

```py
# Change the action associated with your option to action='store'
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--option1', action='store')


def pytest_configure(config):
    x = config.getoption('option1')
    print(x)  # Any logic that uses option value
```

**Output:**

```
pytest -s --option1=Y -c=test.py
Y
============================================================================= test session starts ==============================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.8.5, pytest-6.0.1, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
```

You can find details on available action(s) and more here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action

Comment: Thanks.  Gave this a try but got the error, "ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...] pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --option1".  Complete trace and code is an edit to my question.

Comment: Hi Dave, You need to use this, 

```parser.addoption('--option1', action='store')```

Edited answer, look at the Solution section of the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Downgrade pytest version to pytest7.1.0 , it resolve the issue for me.

Answer (score -2):

I think order matters in this case.

Try `pytest -c tests/my_test.py --option1=Y`

Comment: I think "-c" is meant to indicate an ".ini" file, no?  Running the command as you have it gives the error, "ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...], pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --option1=Y, inifile: /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/my_project/tests/my_test.py".  Removing "-c" still give an error "ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...], pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --option1=Y, inifile: /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/my_project/pytest.ini".