# Fetch command line argument and assign it to global variable using pytest

Tags: python, pytest

Have to fetch the command line arguments and assign them to global variables in the python script under nontest modules using a pytest.

**Example Code:**

```
# conftest.py
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--name", action="store", default="default name")
```

```
# test_sample.py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def name(req):
    return req.getoption("name")

# Here, I require the command line argument assigned to a global variable "glob_name"
glob_name = name

foo="""
def test_"""+glob_name+"""():
    print("Inside test function with a global name")
"""
exec(foo)
```

**Command Used:**

```
pytest -q -s test_sample.py --name google
```

**Error occurred:**

```
========================================================================================== ERRORS ==========================================================================================
_____________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting test_sample.py ______________________________________________________________________________
test_sample.py:10: in <module>
    def test_"""+glob_name+"""():
E   TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'function' objects
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
1 error in 0.12 seconds
```

**Expected Output:**

```
It should have to append the str "google" to the test function name and have to execute that function.
```

I would appreciate it if anyone can revert back with a solution for the above-mentioned issue.

Comment: pytest has an ability to select a specific test. https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/usage.html#specifying-tests-selecting-tests

Comment: Is this of some help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42145604/11246056

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you are asking require us to use two hooks at same time.

1. [pytest_generate_tests](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/parametrize.html#pytest-generate-tests) : To implement your own parametrization scheme.
2. [pytest_collection_modifyitems](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html?highlight=pytest_collection_modifyitems#pytest.hookspec.pytest_collection_modifyitems) : To rename based on your requirement.

You can use below code for same

**conftest.py**

```
import pytest


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--name", action="store", default="default name")


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def get_name(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--name")


def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if "get_name" in metafunc.fixturenames:
        if metafunc.config.getoption("name"):
            param = str(metafunc.config.getoption("name"))
        else:
            param = "default"
        metafunc.parametrize("get_name", [param])


def pytest_collection_modifyitems(items):
    for item in items:
        # check that we are altering a test named `test_run_name`
        # and it accepts the `get_name` arg
        if item.originalname == 'test_run_name' and 'get_name' in item.fixturenames:
            item._nodeid = item.nodeid.replace(']', '').replace('run_name[', '')
```

**test_sample.py**

```
def test_run_name(get_name):
    print("Inside test function with a global name {}".format(get_name))
    assert True
```

**Run using cmd**

```
pytest -v -s test_sample.py --name google
```

**Output in Console:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you alpha89. It is working with this code.

Is it possible to pass multiple arguments at once and execute the test function with all of them?

Comment: How many arguments needs to be passed at once?

Comment: Say around 5 to 10. Is it possible?

Comment: All arguments to be used in same test or diff tests?

Comment: Exactly, I am looking for a similar code.