# Can I process a custom command line option of PyTest outside of a test?

Tags: python, pytest

I want to access my custom command line options before any test processed in order to get the input and output path of the files that need to be tested.

```
# content of conftest.py
import pytest
from pathlib import Path

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--inpath", type=Path, action="store", help="Test case input")
    parser.addoption("--anticipated_outpath", type=Path, action="store", help="Anticipated output")
```

```
# content of test_unit.py
import pytest
from pytest import mark

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def add_custom_config(request):
    config = request.config
    global inpath
    inpath = config.getoption('--inpath', default="testfolder/test1.txt")
    global anticipated_outpath
    anticipated_outpath = config.getoption('--anticipated_outpath', default="expected_test1_output.txt")

in_file = open(inpath,'r')
actual_output_total = in_file.read().split('\n')
expected_output_file = open(anticipated_outpath,'r')
expected_output_total = expected_output_file.read().split('\n')

def test_unit_test1():
    actual_output = actual_output_total[1:3]
    expected_output = expected_output_total[0:2]
    assert actual_output == expected_output
```

When I invoke test file test_unit.py with:

```
pytest -v --inpath=testfolder/test1.txt
```

Get the following error:

```
E   NameError: name 'inpath' is not defined
```

So how can I process my command line options outside of tests?

EDIT - please re-open the question:
[Suggested answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40880259/how-to-pass-arguments-in-pytest-by-command-line) does not solve my problem, because that command line option is processed inside a test and the point of my question is how to process command line options **outside** of a test:

```
def test_print_name(name):
    print ("Displaying name: %s" % name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting `NameError` because you're trying to access a global variable that does not exist.

Creating your two variables in the global scope before your function will solve that particular exception.

```
import pytest
from pytest import mark

inpath, anticipated_outpath = None, None 

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def add_custom_config(request):
    # Rest of code
```

Comment: Yes, that's true so thanks! But it does not solve my original problem. Variables `inpath` and `anticipated_outpath` will be None in this case, instead of getting the values from command line options.

Comment: @macuko The `default` arg should be part of `addoption`, not `getoption`. But regardless your block of code in between the fixture and  function will not get executed in the order I think you expect. I recommend reading more about the concept of pytest hooks/fixtures.

Comment: Thanks, I will check the suggested topics from the documentation.