# how to pass Excel file name via command line to pytest

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, pytest, google-maps-markers, conftest

I am running my automation scripts on 2 portals(STAGE AJS, STAGE IAM). So I have stored those portal URL and credentials in a .xlsx file and I am using the .env file where I am reading the filepath.

```
**.env file**
#Stage environment
filepath = "ExcelFiles/StageAJSDataSource.xlsx"
#filepath = "ExcelFiles/StageIAMDataSource.xlsx"
```

Everytime when I run the pytest, I have to manually uncomment the filepath in the .env file to choose the excel file.
can I pass this filepath in command line and run only on particular portal? Please suggest me.

Comment: duplicate of [How to pass arguments in pytest by command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40880259/how-to-pass-arguments-in-pytest-by-command-line).